VBA Type Mismatch when trying to add an empty cell and double
I'm trying to get the culminative total from a series of cells. However, whenever I try to add an empty cell to the total variable it returns a type mismatch. Furthermore, when tried on a different excel it works for some reason?
 For Each orow In tbl.ListRows
                Let name = orow.Range(2).Value
                Let projname = orow.Range(1).Value
                If InStr(1, pc, name, 1) > 0 Then
                    '=== Insert Single Row and Proj ===
                    curcell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
                    Range(wsT.Cells(row, "A"), wsT.Cells(row + curcell.MergeArea.Count, "A")).MergeCells = True
                    wsT.Rows(row + curcell.MergeArea.Count - 1).Interior.Color = RGB(193, 240, 200)
                    wsT.Cells(row + curcell.MergeArea.Count - 1, 2) = projname
                    For i = 1 To 11
                        '=== Copy Specific Loading into Row ===
                        wsT.Cells(row + curcell.MergeArea.Count - 1, i + 2) = orow.Range(i + 3).Value
                        loadtotal = loadtotal + orow.Range(i + 3).Value 'ERROR HERE
                    Next i
                    wsT.Cells(row + curcell.MergeArea.Count - 1, 15) = loadtotal
                End If
    
            Next orow

I tried if Not Cell Empty and for some reason is able to add empty cells but only adds empty cells.

Maybe test the value with IsNumeric ?

We can't see your declarations. How is declared loadtotal?

Is it possible that you cell is not empty but containing an empty string (for example returned by a function?

Try either If IsNumeric(orow.Range(i + 3).Value) Then: loadtotal = loadtotal + orow.Range(i + 3).Value: End If (suggested by CLR)  or the more accurate If VarType(orow.Range(i + 3).Value) = vbDouble Then: loadtotal = loadtotal + orow.Range(i + 3).Value: End If.

Side notes: Let is deprecated. name shadows the Name statement.

orow.Range(2) is not in the same row as orow! Same goes for orow.Range(i + 3)... is that intended?
